# Line is too long. Django PEP8

Tags: python, django, pep8

PEP8 info:

```
models.py:10:80: E501 line too long (83 > 79 characters)
```

Models.py:

```
field = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='abcdefgh')
```

How to correctly write this line?

Comment: I think it's fair to ignore this specific pep8 rule for django projects. [Django itself makes that exception](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/).

Comment: The question is good and not localized at all

Comment: Don't forget from PEP 8 itself – "know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes style guide recommendations just aren't applicable. When in doubt, use your best judgment. Look at other examples and decide what looks best"

Comment: If you're using flake8, you can make the linter ignore this error by adding the comment `# noqa: E501` to the end of the line (cf. http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/3.1.1/user/ignoring-errors.html).

Answer (score 30):

It's "correct", PEP8 just flags lines over 79 characters long. But if you're concerned about that, you could write it like this:

```
field = TreeForeignKey('self',
                       null=True,
                       blank=True,
                       related_name='abcdefgh')
```

Or this:

```
field = TreeForeignKey(
    'self',
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    related_name='abcdefgh',
)
```

Or, really, any other style that would break the single line into multiple shorter lines.

Comment: That trailing command looks a little iffy in the second example

Comment: @D.Shawley: Trailing commas are fine in Python. (I usually put them when using such a coding style to avoid syntax issues if additional arguments are passed to the function.)

Comment: they are fine if you are using keyword and/or variable list arguments.

Comment: @D.Shawley: They'll work when a function has a fixed list of arguments, too.

Comment: Hmm.. they do.  I guess I found the one thing that I will learn today ;)

Comment: @D.Shawley Don't stop at one ;)

Answer (score 18):

I just found this neat program called autopep8! https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8

```
pip install autopep8
autopep8 -i models.py
```

You can also do (recursively):

```
autopep8 -ri package/
```

Auto PEP8 only makes safe changes to the files, only changing layout, not code logic.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you! :) When used in conjunction with [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/), I almost don't miss using a full-fledged IDE.

Answer (score 9):

If you have some ridiculous long string that isn't very convenient to break into pieces (thinking about things like Sentry DSNs, the occasional module in MIDDLEWARE or INSTALLED_APPS), you can just put `# noqa` at the end of the line and the linters will ignore the line.  Use sparingly thou and definitely not for the case you asked for.

Comment: I am using flake8 and black package. #noqa works. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is very subjective. I'd write, if I were following E501 strictly:

```
field = TreeForeignKey('self',
                       null=True,
                       blank=True,
                       related_name='abcdefgh')
```

I usually consider 100 too long, not 80.

Comment: @hayden: that's a style guide for the Python standard library. It's perfectly fine to consider a different line length preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I usually split that to line up the parameters one level of indentation deeper than the original line, like:

```
field = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True,
    blank=True, related_name='abcdefgh')
```

Especially if `TreeForeignKey` is something like `TreeForeignKeyWithReferencesToSomethingElse`, in which case all the parameters would start out to the far right of the window if you lined them all up with the opening parenthesis. If any of the parameters had a long name like `defaultvalueforcertaincircumstances`, you might not be able to fit the whole thing in under 80 columns:

```
field = TreeForeignKeyWithReferencesToSomethingElse('self',
                                                    defaultvalueforcertaincircumstances='foo')
```

I also prefer to put multiple function parameters on the same line (except when it just doesn't look right; I'm not a purist!) so that vertical space isn't overly expanded, causing me to spend more time scrolling around in my editor than otherwise necessary.

Comment: The first one is not really happy with PEP8 - note the first "No" in the [Indentation section](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

Answer (score 0):

`autopep8` can solve spacing issues in files and entire project as well, here is a link to the documentation: https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8

1. `pip install --upgrade autopep8`
2. `autopep8 --in-place --aggressive --aggressive <path_with_python_filename>`
   ex: `autopep8 --in-place --aggressive --aggressive C://a/test.py`