# Pycode style E501 line too long (118 > 79 characters)

Tags: python, pycodestyle

```
charr_prob = float(self.char_freq(kgram, char) * 1.0 / (self.kgram_freq(kgram) * 1.0))
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Line is too long. Django PEP8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143284/line-is-too-long-django-pep8)

Answer (score 1):

Long lines are not necessarily a bad thing if they do not affect readability. It's a matter of taste. You can disable the warning by adding `# noqa`, or you can split the line into multiple ones:

E.g. using parentheses:

```
charr_prob = (float(self.char_freq(kgram, char) * 1.0 
              / (self.kgram_freq(kgram) * 1.0)))
```

As `float` already uses parentheses:

```
charr_prob = float(self.char_freq(kgram, char) * 1.0
             / (self.kgram_freq(kgram) * 1.0))
```

You can also use `\` at the end of the first line to include the second one in the current expression. Here, it will be redundant with the parentheses defined for `float`, but assuming that you remove the call to `float`, it will be:

```
charr_prob = (self.char_freq(kgram, char) * 1.0) \
             / (self.kgram_freq(kgram) * 1.0)
```

You can also simplify the expression whenever possible. Assuming you're using Python3 (and thus `/` is not the integer division):

```
charr_prob = self.char_freq(kgram, char) / self.kgram_freq(kgram)
```

Or, for Python2 (79 characters!):

```
charr_prob = float(self.char_freq(kgram, char)) / float(self.kgram_freq(kgram))
```

Or, as suggested by @Blender, even:

```
charr_prob = float(self.char_freq(kgram, char)) / self.kgram_freq(kgram)
```

... the second `float` being unecessary as the first operand of `/` is already a float. Another possibility is to import the behavior of `/` from Python3 to Python2:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Comment: To make it shorter, you don't need more than a single `float` in the Python 2 version. You could also do `from __future__ import division` and use the Python 3 version in both cases.

Comment: Right! Thanks @Blender. I edited my answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: pycodestyle seems to be counting the indentation as characters also
charr_prob = (float(self.char_freq(kgram, char) * 1.0 is only 53 characters long. But pycodestyle counts it as 87 characters long including the indentation

Comment: You have 34 characters just to indent the code? That's a lot (and not a multiple of 4 or 8, btw ;-) One possibility in that case could be to move part of the code in separate functions. Another possibility is to simply ignore the warning, as PEP8 is just a guideline ;)